# send special character "~-enter" in expect script

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect

i need some help please.

i write a little testing script for my daily work.

in that script i will connect to a server console.

here is my expect part:

```
export TMPEXPECT=$(mktemp /home/user/tmp/expect.XXXXXX)
chmod 700 $TMPEXPECT

echo "Verbinde auf console..."
        cat <<< '#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh root:ttyS'"$port"'@'"$console"'
expect {        "*gnore*" { send "i\r\r"}        }
expect {        "\n" {send "\r"}        }
expect {        "\n" {send "\r"}        }
sleep 2
expect {        "\n" {send "\r"}        }
expect {        "\n" {send "~.\r"}        }
expect eof
' > $TMPEXPECT
$TMPEXPECT
```

the output looks like this:

```
spawn ssh root:ttyS33@console

A non-empty Data Buffering File was found. Choose which action
should be performed ( (I)gnore, (D)isplay, (E)rase or (S)how and erase ) : I

Welcome to Special Dedicated-Server Linux (x86_64) Version 5.5.1 - Kernel 4.4.77-9.1.x86_64 (ttyS0).

server login:
Welcome to Special Dedicated-Server Linux (x86_64) Version 5.5.1 - Kernel 4.4.77-9.1.x86_64 (ttyS0).

server login:
Welcome to Special Dedicated-Server Linux (x86_64) Version 5.5.1 - Kernel 4.4.77-9.1.x86_64 (ttyS0).

server login: ~.
```

you can see the connection works.

but i have a problems.

after pressing 3 times enter i want to close the connection.

if i want do this normal i will press "alt gr + . enter" an the connection is close.

```
server login: Connection to console closed.
```

but this doesn't work in expect as you can see above :(

do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to send the `~-` to SSH or to the console SSH is connect to? Because `~` sequences are special to SSH, and SSH will grab those by default.

Comment: trying to send the `~-` to the SSH connection to the console in the script. i hope you understand what i mean

Comment: What happens if you use `spawn ssh -e none root:ttyS'"$port"'@'"$console"'` ?

Comment: You could also try `send "~B"` to send a break to the remote, or if you dont use `-e none` as suggested by thrig then double the tilde character `~` if you want it to be received by the remote instead of acted on by ssh, as in `send "~~B"`. Also, you might ensure your locale is C, in case the tilde you see is not an ascii tilde but some unicode lookalike. `export LC_ALL=C`. You can replace the tilde by the hex equivalent `\x7e`, eg send "\x7eB"`.

Comment: @thrig doesn't change anything

Comment: @meuh doesn't work. if i use the export then are the characters wrong like this "▒▒▒▒'Њ▒▒▒▒f▒P:y▒▒▒ϊ▒ϊϊǊ▒▒▒▒" 
i have seen i make a mistake it is not "alt gr + - enter" it is "alt gr + . enter" but the result is the same

Comment: So you normally type the ssh disconnect command `~.`.  There is probably no point doing this in your script. After expecting the last `\n`, simply stop the script there, without the `expect eof`. This will close the ssh. Run the script a second time to see if the new connection starts the same as before, i.e. cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

okay i answer my self because it is better to read.

i tested a little...i have delete the "expect eof" it seem to be better.

```
cat <<< '#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh -e none root:ttyS'"$port"'@'"$console"'

expect {
        "*regular*" { send "1\r"}
        "default" { send "i\r"}
        }

expect {
        "*gnore*" { send "i\r"}
        }

expect {
        "*\n*" {send "\r"}
        }
sleep 5
expect {
        "*\n*" {send "\r"}
        }
sleep 2
expect {
        "*\n*" {send "\r"}
}
sleep 2
' > $TMPEXPECT
$TMPEXPECT
echo ""
echo ""
echo "this is a test after the expect and expect eof part"
```

with this code i get that output:

```
spawn ssh -e none root:ttyS33@console

A non-empty Data Buffering File was found. Choose which action
should be performed ( (I)gnore, (D)isplay, (E)rase or (S)how and erase ) : I

Welcome to Special Dedicated-Server Linux (x86_64) Version 5.6.0 - Kernel 4.4.89-9.1.x86_64 (ttyS0).

server login:
Welcome to Special Dedicated-Server Linux (x86_64) Version 5.6.0 - Kernel 4.4.89-9.1.x86_64 (ttyS0).

server login:

this is a test after the expect and expect eof part
```

seems like the connection is closed correctly. i think so.
i have test a normal connect.
and i don't get a message like this:

```
*
* * * ttyS33 is being used by (root) !!!
*

1 - Initiate a regular session
2 - Initiate a sniff session
3 - Send messages to another user
4 - Kill session(s)
5 - Quit

Enter your option :
```

this is what i get if a connection is not close correctly.

so i think this case is closed.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to send `exit\r` to close the ssh connection instead of ending the script at the eof.